# menu item required to edit content

Tags: nodes

I need to add a menu item in my User menu which provides the facility for users to amend the content of a Content Type ( Sectors) i.e. so they can amend a sector. The User Menu only appears of course for logged in users.

I have tried setting up a menu option in the User menu which links to a View which displays all the Sectors so the logged in user can select one and amend it, this works fine, but the menu option is still displayed for anonymous users as well.

I have 'node/add' for other menu options to create content for content types, they behave properly in the User menu i.e. only appear when a user is logged in, how do I have an edit option for Sectors which only appears for logged-in user in the User Menu?

Comment: Is the view itself also accessible for anonymous users? You could create a view page with permission: role and add a menu entry from there as well. This shouldn't be visible for anonymus.

Comment: thank you so much, i just edited the view, changed Permission to Role and selected the role required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achieved by setting the Permission of the View to Role and selecting the role required.